# Validate same textbox based on dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown and a textbox. I have populated dropdown with datatypes like number, character, float etc. Based on dropdown value need to validate textbox value

```
$("#textbox").on("keydown",function (e) { 
    var dropdown_val = $("#dropdown option:selected").val(); 
    if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && dropdown_val === $.trim('NUM')) {     
        $("#transac_errmsg" + transaction_hid).html("Digits only").show().fadeOut("slow"); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 

    if ((e.which <= 64 && e.which >= 91) || (e.which <= 96 && e.which >= 123) && dropdown_val === $.trim('CHAR')) { 
        $("#transac_errmsg" + transaction_hid).html("Letters only").show().fadeOut("slow"); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 
});
```

Only first part of if works for me and not other else part. Help me to do this.

Comment: I haven't read the question yet, but there is a missing double quotes `"` after `keyup`

Comment: I believe he is writing a pseudocode.

Comment: Adding your HTML code and proper jQuery code would be helpful.

Comment: Actual Code : $("#textbox").on("keydown",function (e) {
    var dropdown_val=$("#dropdown  option:selected").val();
         if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && dropdown_val === $.trim('NUM')) {
        $("#transac_errmsg"+transaction_hid).html("Digits only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               e.preventDefault();
    }
  if ((e.which <= 64 && e.which >= 91) || (e.which <= 96 && e.which >= 123) && dropdown_val === $.trim('CHAR') ) {
   $("#transac_errmsg"+transaction_hid).html("Letters only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               e.preventDefault();
    }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

For the keycodes, visit [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

For the actual validation, see this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery#answer-995193).

**HTML**

```
<select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="number">Number</option>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="float">Float</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myInput"  value="" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#myInput").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var dropdown = $("#myDropdown").val();
    var inputValue = $(this).val();

    if(dropdown === "number") {
        //"Do your number validation here
    } else if(dropdown === "text") {
        //Do your text validation here
    } else  if(dropdown === "float") {
        //Do your float validation here
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/phdyvnzv/4/)